# Taxonomy in Joomla 3

Tags: component, development, tags

Can someone explain how to use taxonomies in Joomla 3, in the context of developing a custom application? I can find no documentation of how to implement this. I explored the new tagging system, but it seems not quite ready for prime-time-- none of the "official" Joomla docs on how to use it in a component resulted in success-- they were either out of date or the underlying code was faulty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [document](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x%3aUsing_Tags_in_an_Extension) which will help you while integrating with Joomla tag system.
I have integrated tag system in some of my extensions and it works fine.

Although this document is not sufficient enough to answer all of your questions but it will surely guide you through most of the doubts.

At some places i changed my extension code (not as per the document) so as to support joomla tagging since there are some MVC structure variation exists in my extension.

Yes, in the earlier version of Joomla 3.1 there were few bugs in the tagging system but over the time those issues has been rectified and now it has reached to a stable state.